# Why is it saying that calcAverage is not a function, when it is

Tags: javascript, function

I created a simple function to calcluate the average of 3 numbers:

```
let calcAverage = (v1,v2,v3) =>{

calcAverage = v1+v2+v3 / 3;

return calcAverage
}

const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71)
const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71)
console.log(d1)
```

if you comment out: `const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71)`then you will notice that the `const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71)`works, but why does it say 'Uncaught TypeError: calcAverage is not a function for this line of code: `const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71)`? this doesn't make any sense to me. how do I make both of them work?  and why is it even saying that calcAverage is not a function i the first place?

Comment: `calcAverage = v1 + ...` overwrites the global declartion as you're not using `var/let/const` before you define it, so it's being set to a number when you first run it

Comment: Are you trying to do a recursive stuff ?

Comment: Also your function and variable names are same, it is not looking readable and may cause some ambiguity.

Comment: After `d1`'s calcAverage is been executed, the then calcAverage function becomes an integer or float depending on the result of `v1+v2+v3/3`. So solve this issue, please, use a different variable name on returning your calculations. e.g. use `let calcAll = (v1+v2+v3)/3` instead of using the arrow function name.

Answer (score 1):

Because you reassigned `calcAverage` in this line

```js
calcAverage = v1+v2+v3 / 3;
```

which made `calcAverage` a `number` value instead of a function

why don't you just return this calculations immediately

```js
return v1+v2+v3 / 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `calcAverage` for the first time, it indeed is a function. However, you overwrite it within the function itself to be a `number`:

```
calcAverage = v1+v2+v3 / 3;
```

Simply change the variable name inside the function to make it work as you expect:

```
const calcAverage = (v1,v2,v3) =>{

    const result = v1+v2+v3 / 3; 

    return result;
}

const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71);
const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71);
console.log(d1);
```

---

**Update:**

To clearly see the issue, you can log out the type of `calcAverage` for each of the function calls:

```js
let calcAverage = (v1,v2,v3) =>{
  calcAverage = v1+v2+v3 / 3; 
  return calcAverage;
}
    
console.log("Type before first call: ", typeof calcAverage);
const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71);
console.log("Type before second call: ", typeof calcAverage);
const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71);
```

This nicely shows the advantage of using `const` over using `let` for actual constants, by the way. If you would have declared `calcAverage` as a `const`, you wouldn't have run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

i found a  variable inside the function with the same function name . so when you call calAverage second time it is not a function instead it is a resultof  of some calculation.
also i made function as a constant one

```js
const calcAverage = (v1, v2, v3) =>
  {
  let calcAverageVal = v1 + v2 + v3 / 3
  return calcAverageVal
  }

const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23, 71)
const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23, 71)

console.log(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this problem is use a different variable name to hold the calculated value inside the calcAverage arrow function.

```
let calcAverage = (v1,v2,v3) =>{

   let calcValue = (v1+v2+v3) / 3;
   // it is recommended you bracket your numerator so as not to confuse the calcuation
   // because leaving it as v1+v2+v3 / 3 will solve the maths as v1+v2+(v3/3)

   return calcValue;
}

const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71);
const k1 = calcAverage(44, 23,71);
console.log(d1)
```

As for me, i did suggest you use `const` when declaring an arrow function. It helps to make the function unmanipulatable

Answer (score 1):

It is all about scope dependency

1. in a first time you define `calcAverage` as a function
2. then inside this function you redefine this elemenent as a number

=> on the first call : it is a function
=> on the second call : it is no more a function (it is a number)

is you want to avoid anytime this kind of problem, you have to **always declare all of your variables**

And also it is recommanded for begginners to [make your code on strict mode ('use strict'; directive)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode) wich is help you to avoid this kind of mistakes

sample code:

```js
'use strict';  // on first line, for all the code

let calcAverage = (v1, v2, v3) =>
  {
  let calcAverage = v1 + v2 + v3 / 3;  // define a 'new' locale variable
//╙╨╨─────────────────────────────────// within the scope of this function
  return calcAverage
  }

const d1 = calcAverage(44, 23, 71)
const k1 = calcAverage(40, 23, 71)

console.log(d1) // 90.666...
console.log(k1) // 86.666...
```